# How to add on each ng-content some text?

Tags: angular

```
        <app-component  [date]="'13.10.2022'">
              <app-test-content [content]="content"></app-test-content>
            </app-component >
```

```
Here is from app-component

<div *ngFor="let number of [1,2,3]">
  <h1>{{date}}</h1>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

How can I put the date after each ng-content

At the moment is like that:

13.10.2022

13.10.2022

13.10.2022

Title

Pellentesque id sagittis nisl. Mauris euismod quam ut est tempor, vitae lobortis dolor rhoncus.

Title 2

Pellentesque id sagittis nisl. Mauris euismod quam ut est tempor, vitae lobortis dolor rhoncus 2.

Title 3

Pellentesque id sagittis nisl. Mauris euismod quam ut est tempor, vitae lobortis dolor rhoncus3

But I need :

13.10.2022

Title
Pellentesque id sagittis nisl. Mauris euismod quam ut est tempor, vitae lobortis dolor rhoncus.

13.10.2022

Title 2
Pellentesque id sagittis nisl. Mauris euismod quam ut est tempor, vitae lobortis dolor rhoncus 2.

13.10.2022

Title 3
Pellentesque id sagittis nisl. Mauris euismod quam ut est tempor, vitae lobortis dolor rhoncus3.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do an Angular content projection inside a loop, In order to do an Angular content projection inside a loop, You need to use  `ngTemplateOutlet` and not ng-content

The ngTemplateOutlet directive let you create embedded view from a TemplateRef. The TemplateRef represents an embedded template that can be used to instantiate embedded views.

In the parent component:

```html
<app-child [date]="'13.10.2022'">
    <ng-template #textSlot let-text>
        {{content}}
    </ng-template>
</app-child>
```

In the child component:

```html
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let number of [1,2,3]">
    <h1>{{date}}</h1>
    <div>
      <ng-container
        *ngTemplateOutlet="textSlotTmpl, 
                     context: { $implicit: text }"
      ></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

child.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, Input, ContentChild, TemplateRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"]
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() date: string;
  @ContentChild("textSlot") textSlotTmpl: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

then you will have your expected results.

Comment: Sorry, but in In the parent component I need to  <app-test-content [content]="content"></app-test-content> this selector. It takes from server all data that are loaded in admin line Title, paragraph, image, ... etc. And all this data is returned by this selector and I can't remove or change it